# How to customize VSkeletonLoader?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

In my Vuetify-Project I have a VDataTable and I want to use VSkeletonLoaders. But how can I do the following changes?

Here is the simplified [Vuetify-Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

1. I want just as many items per row as columns exists. In this case 4.
2. The divider should have the width of the VDataTable (possible with px-n8, but still the following problem:)
3. The Text-VSkeletonLoaders should have an x-padding like normal VDataTableItems. They shouldn't start and end at the same x-point as the divider.
4. The last line (probably from the VDataTable) should be removed.
5. The Text-VSkeletonLoaders should be centered between the divider at the top and the bottom.

[image: My problems]

I can't find any fix for these scenarios. The [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/skeleton-loaders/#api) seems like there is no way to customize it as I want.

Probably, I need to place a VSkeletonLoader in each item-Slot of the VDataTable. But also in this case: How can I do it?